# Where is $(z^2 +1)\Re(z)$ holomorph?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to calculate the points $z$ where $f'(z)$ exists with $f(z) = (z^2+1)\Re(z)$. By checking the Cauchy-Riemann equations I got $z = \pm i$. Is this possible ? Must $f$ not be holomorph on an open subset of $\mathbb C$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. $f$ is holomorph nowhere but it derivative may exists in some points. A holomorph function is a function which is complex differentiable in an open subset.

Comment: Is it then correct to say that if the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied in $z_0 \in \mathbb C$, then $f'(z_0)$ exists ? I was wondering, because the theorem about these equations says always let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb C$ with $U$ open subset in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Yeah it exists there. You have $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ so you surely do have an open subset

Comment: According to http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy-Riemann_Equations I must have that the equations are satisfied in the whole domain of $f$. But how can I then check what the (isolated) points are where $f'$ exists ?

Comment: Oh as far as I can see they don't distinguish between complex differentiable and holormophic. That may be because being complex differentiable in only one point is not that interessting. As you will see complex differentiable on an open subset is a very strong thing

Comment: Just for clarification: In order to compute ALL points $z$ where $f'(z)$ exists (thus complex differentiable is) it is sufficient to check in which points $z$ the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied ?

Comment: We defined complex differentiable via real differentiable + satisfying cauchy riemann, How did you define it ?

Comment: Let $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb C$ where $\Omega$ is a region (open and connected). If $$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0, h \in \mathbb C \backslash \{0 \}} \frac{ f(z_0 + h) - f(z_0) } h $$ exists then $f'(z_0)$ is this limit and we say $f$ is holomorphic at the point $z_0$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9169/discussion-between-dominic-michaelis-and-andre)